# Loop is not using the full IP but only the first number

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to get the location of every ip in the database now is the problem its only using the first number and not the full ip for some reason so im getting the error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(ipinfo.io/8): failed to open stream: HTTP
>   request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in

Now is my question how can i make it work with the full ip since i don't have an clue anymore.

```
$result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email");
$row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;
$ip_rows = $result_ip->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$country_ip_data = array();

foreach ($ip_rows as $ip_row) {
    $ip = $ip_row['ip'];
    if (!$ip) {
        continue;
    }
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $country = $details->country;
    if (!isset($country_ip_data[$country])) {
        $country_ip_data[$country] = array();
    }
    $country_ip_data[$country][] = $ip;
}

var_dump($country_ip_data);
```

Final result should be an array with all the countries so i can filter it on each country and put them in a map chart.

Comment: What `var_dump($ip_rows)` returning?

Comment: before `foreach` do `"echo "<pre/>";print_r($ip_rows);"` and show the result.

Comment: FYI, there are *rate limits* on that service. So when you max out at 1,000 requests in 10 seconds, at least you'll know why. This is why we can't have nice things.. for free.

Comment: @Marcus Thanks for the information although im not getting the much of request yet but ill look into it maybe i can try to do something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the line `$ip_rows = $result_ip->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`. The mysqli [fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) method returns ONE line from the queried data, so you need to loop through all the lines:

```
$result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email");
$row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;
$country_ip_data = array();

// use a while loop to extract one row's data at a time
while ($ip_row = $result_ip->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $ip = $ip_row['ip'];
    if (!$ip) {
        continue;
    }
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $country = $details->country;
    if (!isset($country_ip_data[$country])) {
        $country_ip_data[$country] = array();
    }
    $country_ip_data[$country][] = $ip;
}

var_dump($country_ip_data);
```

Comment: Thanks this is working i didn't know it returns on one line

Answer (score 2):

**Please try the following:**

```
$result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email");
$row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;
$country_ip_data = array();

while ($ip_row = $result_ip->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $ip = $ip_row['ip'];
    if (!$ip) {
        continue;
    }
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    $details = json_decode($output);
    curl_close($ch); 
    $country = $details->country;
    if (!isset($country_ip_data[$country])) {
        $country_ip_data[$country] = array();
    }
    $country_ip_data[$country][] = $ip;
}
var_dump($country_ip_data);
```

Comment: Not a copy paste see what i am using curl. See fully otherwise dont comment like this

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Okay i will follow this

Comment: This is working aswel but like jay said some explanation is usefull so me and other users will know what they did wrong and what to do next time.

Comment: @marijn I thought file_get_contents is not provide the result, so i used curl. okay marijn.